# How to show that a given set is an vector space?

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, improper-integrals

I have the following set:

$$
\mathcal{V} = \left\{f: \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)^2 e^{-x^2}\,dx < \infty\right\}
$$

To show it is a vector space I need to show that:

1. addition and subtraction are defined
2. The set is closed under linear combinations
3. There is a zero vector.

However, I'm not sure how to show these properties with an integral.

Comment: You do it in exactly the same way.  Make sure that you understand what the objects in your space actually are though... you aren't "*showing these properties with an integral*"... your objects in the space are functions.  Functions who happen to satisfy a property about the alluded to integral, but the objects themselves are still just the functions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions are not supposed to be asked via hyperlink. Pleas write them down in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: So, if you have one function $f$ who satisfies the property, and another function $g$ who satisfies the property, you want to show that $f+g$ satisfies the property and so on...

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Okay, first, what is your addition ? what is your multiplication by a scalar ? what is your 0 vector ? These are the questions you should ask yourself first. Then, you should prove that these operations do produce results that are in V when the arguments are in V

Comment: Your axioms for a vector space are a bit wrong btw, substraction is not part of the axioms defining a vector space (you just need addition and scalar multiplication, substraction can be made with those)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you looking specifically at continuous functions? If not, $\mathcal{V}$ isn't actually a vector space; otherwise, the answer below is a good resolution to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, one just defines such operations pointwise:
$$(f\pm g)(x) = f(x)\pm g(x) \text{ and } (\alpha f)(x) = \alpha f(x).$$
Then,
$$\int (\alpha f \pm \beta g)^2(x)e^{-x^2} \ dx = \alpha^2\int f^2(x)e^{-x^2} \ dx + \beta^2\int g^2(x)e^{-x^2} \ dx \pm 2\alpha\beta\int f(x)g(x)e^{-x^2} \ dx.$$
You should be able to show that the third integral is finite via Hölder's inequality. The first two are finite by definition. For the zero vector take $f \equiv 0$.

Edit (to address the comment): The operations are defined pointwise and $(f+z)(0) \neq f(0)$, so $z$ is not the zero vector (ie, $f \equiv 0$ is the unique zero vector). The issue you raise wouldn't arise unless perhaps one wanted to put a norm on $\mathcal{V}$ like
$$\|f\|_\mathcal{V} := \int f^2(x)e^{-x^2} \ dx.$$
In that case, one could define an equivalence relation $\sim$ by $f \sim g$ if and only if $f=g\text{ a.e.}$ and then consider $\mathcal{V}/\sim$.

Comment: A fly in the ointment: in a vector space, the zero vector must be unique. So something like $z(x)=1$ if $x=0$ and $z(x)=0$ else is a zero vector in the sense that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f+z)^2 e^{-x^2}dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^2 e^{-x^2}dx$ for any $f\in\mathcal{V}$. Perhaps OP is looking at continuous $f$, in which case this problem disappears.

Comment: @FearfulSymmetry I don't think that this matters in this setting. The operations are defined pointwise.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm being dense, but why are operations defined pointwise? Isn't the defining feature finite definite integral?

Comment: @FearfulSymmetry As far as I know, that's just how one usually defines vector space operations for function spaces. There are, of course, situations where one doesn't do this (eg, distributions), but I was assuming that the OP was at least dealing with measurable functions.

Comment: haha fair enough, i've been wrong before

Comment: @FearfulSymmetry I think we all have lol. I think the issue is that the details are rather sparse in the OP. They don't specify where $\mathcal{V}$ lives, etc.